# How to hide a form and show up only when selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, debugging

I want to build my first program. Yesterday I started coding and I can't stop, but I'm having trouble with the `onchange` function. I want `<form id="squareA">` to show up only when Square is selected on my option list. Same goes for the other list. I haven't made their forms yet, because I'm stuck at squareA.

Here is my code.

```
<script>
  function myShapes() {
    var a1 = document.getElementById("shapes").value;
    if(a1.value == option.value) {
      document.getElementById("square").value = ("squareA");
    } else {
      document.getElementById("square").disabled = true;
    }
  }
}
</script>

<legend>Calculate Dimension</legend>
<select id="shapes" onchange="myShapes">
  <option selected="selected" value="none">Select Shape</option>
  <option onselect="mySquare" id="square" value="Square">Square</option>
  <option onselect="myRect" id="rect" value="Rectangle">Rectangle</option>
  <option onselect="myComb" id="comb" value="Combined">Combined</option>
  <option  onselect="myStrap" id="strap" value="Strap">Strap</option>
  <option  onselect="myTrap" id="trap" value="Trapezoidal">Trapezoidal</option>
</select>
<form id="squareA">
  <div disabled="disabled" id="disa">
    <input id="squareD" type="text" placeholder="Dimension"/> by
    <input id="squareD2" type="text" placeholder="Dimension"/>
  </div>
</form>
</fieldset>
```

Inside the long line is the code that's not working or wrong.

Comment: You need to call the function on change like `onchange="myShapes()"`

Comment: Are you using jQuery library for the page

Comment: no sir.. its suggested on the tag list ..

Comment: what else is my error sir?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/0n81q7fj/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the function in the `onchange` attribute, then check the value in the change handler and set the display value of the form

```js
function myShapes() {
  /*On change check the value of the select and based on it set the display css value to either none or block*/
  document.getElementById('squareA').style.display = document.getElementById('shapes').value == 'Square' ? 'block' : 'none'
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<legend>Calculate Dimension</legend>
<select id="shapes" onchange="myShapes()">
  <!--Need to call the function here, id add () at the end-->
  <option selected="selected" value="none">Select Shape</option>
  <option value="Square">Square</option>
  <option value="Rectangle">Rectangle</option>
  <option value="Combined">Combined</option>
  <option value="Strap">Strap</option>
  <option value="Trapezoidal">Trapezoidal</option>
</select>
<form id="squareA" style="display:none;">
  <!--Hide the form on page load-->
  <div disabled="disabled" id="disa">
    <input id="squareD" type="text" placeholder="Dimension" />by
    <input id="squareD2" type="text" placeholder="Dimension" />
  </div>
</form>
```